# Unable to view Pelican site in Development Server

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pelican

I wanted to try hosting a Pelican site on S3, following the instructions available [here](https://kawashi.me/how-to-host-your-blog-using-pelican-amazon-s3-and-cloudflare.html). 
I created the appropriate folders, and saved the test post in `.md` format in the content folder as well. 
On running `$ make devserver`, I get the following error:

```
User-MacBook-Air:my_blog user$ make devserver
/Volumes/HDD3TB/05. Work/07. Github Pages/pelican/my_blog/develop_server.sh restart
make: /Volumes/HDD3TB/05.: No such file or directory
make: *** [devserver] Error 1
```

I can't figure out why it says 'No such file or directory'. On listing out the files in the root directory, I can see that these files exist:

```
Makefile        fabfile.py      publishconf.py
content         output
develop_server.sh   pelicanconf.py
```

How could I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the whitespace in the directory name. It thinks `/Volumes/HDD3TB/05.` is the command and rest are command arguments, including `Work/07.`, `Github`, `Pages/pelican/my_blog/develop_server.sh` and `restart`.

I'm not sure how to use devserver so this is supported, otherwise just try without whitespace in your directories.